# Program to import a Microsoft Excel spreadsheet into a MySQL table

Tags: mysql, microsoft-excel

I am looking for a program that can:

- import a Microsoft Excel spreadsheet into a MySQL table
- support cells containing [line breaks](https://superuser.com/q/759464/116475)
- support cells containing `'` (and if possible any other character)

If possible:

- Free
- Windows 7
- allows to specify which columns we want to import

Comment: Do you care what language?

Comment: @NickWilde I would prefer in English but I am surrounded with Europeans and Asians so I should be able to cope with most languages. Same for programming languages (preference for Python/C++/Java/MATLAB/R).

Comment: Might not be exactly what you're looking for, but I've used excel macros in the past to generate `INSERT` statements (in a separate sheet), which then could easily be exported as `*.sql` files. Wouldn't that be an option? At least it would cover all requirements you've listed ;)

Comment: Excel macros are good too! :)

Comment: Ah yeah I was presuming Unicode support unless specified. I was definitely thinking about the programming language. PHP I see isn't in you're preferred list, but as you say you an probably cope I'll write something up this evening for a PHP solution.

Comment: @NickWilde Thanks, it's okay, I found a solution. A bit tedious though about for a task that seems easy, I'm surprised there is no well-established software to do this.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt unfortunately, those Excel-Macros are always specific to those data sheets, so I cannot setup a full answer on that. But you've already found another (easier) solution, so it's not even a need anymore :)

Answer (score 4):

You can simply export the spreadsheet in Microsoft Excel as a CSV, then use MySQL Workbench's import function:

[image]

This solution supports support cells containing line breaks and support cells containing `'`. However, it doesn't support all special characters as [the Excel to CSV export will mangle the special characters that aren't ASCII characters.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4221176/395857) To perform an Excel to CSV conversion with UTF8 encoding, one solution is to first import the Microsoft Excel spreadsheet into Google drive, then export the Google Drive spreadsheet to a CSV, then use MySQL Workbench's import function.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote an application for importing an Excel spreadsheet into MySQL.  It meets all your other requirements except specifying columns to import, but it will import everything very fast and you can ignore or remove columns you don't want easily enough.   In my biased opinion it is simply the most accurate, easiest and fastest way to import Excel spreadsheets into MySQL.

You can verify that it works with your data before purchase. It will load all your data except some random records will be blank until licensed. There are 2 versions of the program available. An easy to use GUI version and a command-line version which will allow you to automate and append your data to the table. It can handle all versions of Excel and MySQL Server. The process can be fully automated. Once you have the command-line version of the program called from a bat file or your favorite programming language, you can use windows task scheduler to schedule it.  Excel2MySQL is capable of handling huge Excel spreadsheets.

http://excel2mysql.net

[image: screenshot]